# Matching the colour of a legend to the bars in a bargraph python?

Tags: python, seaborn

I'm trying to match the colours of my legend to the bars in a graph. I've specifically highlighted these bars as points of interest, since they are outside of my ylim. Problem is, my legend is displaying the colours as black as opposed to the colours that I want it to.

Below is the function I'm using to graph, as well as the image of the graph.

```py
def seaborn_plot(dataset,times):

    sns.set_style('darkgrid')
    sns.set_color_codes("muted")
    data_ = dataset
    time_list = []
    data_list = []

    for i, v in enumerate(data_):
          if data_[i] > 80000:
              data_list.append(('ED={:.2f}'.format(data_[i])))
              time_list.append(("Hour {}:".format(times[i])))


    df = pd.DataFrame(data = {'times_new':time_list,
                              'data_list':data_list})

    red = 'r'
    blue = 'b'
    colors = []
    for i in range(len(data_)):
        if data_[i] > 80000:
            color = red
            colors.append(color)
        else:
            color2 = blue
            colors.append(color2)

    graph = sns.barplot(x=times, y=data_ , palette = colors, label = time_list)
    graph.set_xlabel("Time (Hours)", fontsize = 10, fontweight = 'bold');
    graph.set_ylabel("Euclidean Distance", fontsize = 10, fontweight = 'bold');
    graph.set_ylim([0, 80000])

    leg = mp.gca().legend(labels = df["times_new"] + df["data_list"])  

    return graph
```

The resulting image:

[image: the image of my graph]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can loop through the generated bars and use the bars that satisfy the condition as handles for the legend.  As seaborn doesn't return a list of bars (in contrast to `plt.bars()`), the bars can be obtained from the returned `ax` (supposing no other bars are drawn yet in the same plot):

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sns

sns.set_style('darkgrid')
sns.set_color_codes("muted")
data_ = np.random.randint(20000, 100000, 24)
times = np.arange(0, 24)

y_limit = 80000
colors = ['r' if d > y_limit else 'b' for d in data_]

ax = sns.barplot(x=times, y=data_, palette=colors)
ax.set_xlabel("Time (Hours)", fontsize=10, fontweight='bold')
ax.set_ylabel("Euclidean Distance", fontsize=10, fontweight='bold')
ax.set_ylim([0, y_limit])

handles = [bar for bar in graph.containers[0] if bar.get_height() > y_limit]
labels = [f'Hour {"  " if h < 10 else ""}{h}: ED={ed:,.0f}' for ed, h in zip(data_, times) if ed > y_limit]
ax.legend(handles, labels, bbox_to_anchor=[1.02, 1], loc='upper left')
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image: resulting plot]

Note that by using the bars as legend handles, this approach would also work when each bar would have an individual color.